# What is the adjective of "daughter-in-law" if she is "the wife of my younger son"?

Tags: adjectives, phrase-requests, kinship-terms

Here, I am confused. I cannot say "younger daughter-in-law" as the order of sons is defined by their age but we can't say that about their wives. So shall I say "my second daughter-in-law"?

Comment: You're right, 'younger daughter-in-law' refers to the woman. You  want to say something where the daughter-in-law is the subject, but the qualification is the age of the son. In English, you have to spell it out as @Daniel did. In your native language, is there a specific term for this or another way of pointing out the 'wife of my younger son'?

Comment: @mitch - we do have a distinction, albeit only coarse. One can say 'छोटी बहू' (choti bahu) which transliterates as 'younger daughter-in-law'. Yet the removal of ambiguation by listeners as mentioned by Daniel here is purely due to the popular use of this particular phrase in Hindi.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you can't use her name (e.g. if you're introducing her), and need to specify exactly *which* daughter-in-law, I'd suggest "my younger son's wife".

*Second daughter-in-law* is ambiguous since you aren't clear on *what* is being counted.  It's not clear which you mean: *younger daughter-in-law*, or *wife of younger son*, or *wife of son who married second*.

Comment: Or "my son's second wife" for that matter.